# langchain.document_loaders.ConfluenceLoader.load giving AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get' while reading all documents from space

Tags: python, langchain, confluence, document-loader

When I try sample code given [here](https://python.langchain.com/docs/integrations/document_loaders/confluence):

```
from langchain.document_loaders import ConfluenceLoader

loader = ConfluenceLoader(
    url="<my confluence link>", username="<my user name>", 
    api_key="<my token>"
)
documents = loader.load(space_key="<my space>", include_attachments=True, limit=1, max_pages=1)
```

I get an error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Here is the last part of the stack:

```
    554     """
    555     Get all pages from space
    556 
   (...)
    568     :return:
    569     """
    570     return self.get_all_pages_from_space_raw(
    571         space=space, start=start, limit=limit, status=status, expand=expand, content_type=content_type
--> 572     ).get("results")
```

Any ideas? I see an issue [here](https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/issues/14113) but it is still open.

I have now also opened [bug](https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/issues/15869) specifically for this issue.

Here is the summary of the fixes required in the original code:

1. Do not suffix the URL with /wiki/home
2. suffix the user name with @ your domain name
3. use ID of the space as in the URL and not its display name

then it works. The error handling is poor to point to these issues otherwise.

Comment: error is clear saying `self.get_all_pages_from_space_raw` function is returnning `str`. what do you expect it to return.

Comment: @Yilmaz that is all internal as far as I am concerned. I just want my load to return something (I don't really care any type, at least at this time) that I can look at.

Comment: here is the problem -[confluence](https://github.com/atlassian-api/atlassian-python-api/blob/master/atlassian/confluence.py). in module `confluence.py` the method `get_all_pages_from_space_raw` returns string and then trying to get `results` from `return self.get_all_pages_from_space_raw(
            space=space, start=start, limit=limit, status=status, expand=expand, content_type=content_type
        ).get("results")`  . need to dig more into it. thanks for raising this concern with the team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ConfluenceLoader` uses
`atlassian-python-api`[github source](https://pypi.org/project/atlassian-python-api/)  and [document reference](https://atlassian-python-api.readthedocs.io/index.html#).
`confluence.py` expects a successful response from **Confluence**. [examples](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/confluence/confluence-rest-api-examples/)

1. verify that the token is still valid - [API tokens](https://id.atlassian.com/manage-profile/security/api-tokens)
2. On the browser if your page is - `https://simpleappdesigner.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/~61dc5d78e67ea2006b1efbc0/pages/65676/Debug+the+python+issue`, then
   `confluence_link='https://simpleappdesigner.atlassian.net'`
   and `space_key="~61dc5d78e67ea2006b1efbc0"`
3. so loader is

```
loader = ConfluenceLoader(
    url=confluence_link, username="simpleappdesigner@gmail.com", 
    api_key=api_key
)
```

and documents as:
`documents = loader.load(space_key=space_key, include_attachments=True, limit=5, max_pages=5)`

with the above changes, i was able to run the following code:

```
confluence_link='https://simpleappdesigner.atlassian.net'

space_key="~61dc5d78e67ea2006b1efbc0"

loader = ConfluenceLoader(
    url=confluence_link, username="simpleappdesigner@gmail.com", 
    api_key=api_key
)
documents = loader.load(space_key=space_key, include_attachments=True, limit=5, max_pages=5)
```

One can access through **postman**, while debugging, following is the way(watch the api url in the below screen snap :) ):
[image]

Hope this helps.Will be happy to help further or in case have questions.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Indeed /wiki/home was causing my issue earlier. However now I am getting 401. I followed the steps outlined in https://docs.searchunify.com/Content/Content-Sources/Atlassian-Jira-Confluence-Authentication-Create-API-Token.htm to get my token. Do I need to check with my admin about this? Does it need any special settings / privileges?

Comment: this flow also leads to - https://id.atlassian.com/manage-profile/security/api-tokens through which I created the API token. i would suggest, debugging through postman/any other tool that API token works okay. pls double-check that you have access to space key, entering user name with email address. them may be check with admin.

Comment: domain suffix in user name did the trick. thanks! have accepted your answer now.

Comment: Awesome! Happy stackoverflow